# NoClassDefFoundError with Maven and a Java Wiki Library

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using a library to make Wikipedia API calls, called the [Java Wiki Bot Framework.](https://github.com/eldur/jwbf) I'm also using Maven for builds, and I've added the framework to the pom.xml just as the github page says. However, when I try to instantiate any of the classes in the library, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/jwbf/core/actions/HttpActionClient
    at com.FactFinder.WikiParser.makeBot(WikiParser.java:21)
    at com.FactFinder.WikiParser.<init>(WikiParser.java:16)
    at com.FactFinder.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jwbf.core.actions.HttpActionClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 3 more
```

[My pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/i7mJMZ7b)

Apparently this is an error that crops up when your jar can't find a class, but I've checked the classpath, and it looks fine. The jar is included in the proper folder, and I've verified that it includes the classes I tried to use. I considered contacting the library author, but I figured its probably more my problem than his.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the Snapshot version 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT? I would strongly suggest to use a final version to avoid issues, of which 3.1.0 seems to be the latest and most popular one:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge</groupId>
  <artifactId>jwbf</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[UPDATE]

1. Follow naming conventions; package name: `com.factfinder` (all lowercase). Fix in both your code, pom, and directory names.
2. Add the version for the maven-jar-plugin

Note that I tried using your pom - it seemed to work for me ...
Are you sure you don't get any other warnings or errors during your maven build? can you do a clean package?

Comment: The snapshot had some features that I couldn't live without.

Comment: A clean package works. The only warning it was giving me before was a warning about the missing version for maven-jar, which as per your suggestion, I have fixed. I also refactored the package name to all lower-case. I still get the same error. I have contacted the author, and the pom seems to work for him as well, It's definitely odd.

Comment: Maybe corrupted local maven repository. Delete the `repository` directory in %HOME%\.m2 (windows) or in ~/.m2 (unix), then again do your `clean package`.

Comment: Deleted the repository, ran clean package. After a lot of downloading, the build passed. I ran my jar, and still got the same error.

Comment: How did you ran the jar? Note that the jar does not contain any of the external dependencies. If you want the jar to work by itself, then you might need to use the maven [shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: I just ran it with Intellij. I am aware of the dependencies problem, which is what the maven-dependency-plugin is for. It copies all the needed jars to a libs folder, which is then included in the manifest. This approach has worked with other libraries, namely json simple, and jsoup.

Comment: I can see that the Classpath is built and added to the jar manifest, but the libraries themselves are not included in the jar. You might need the maven-assembly-plugin or shade.

Comment: It has worked before, so I doubt it's the problem. I was told the separate folder and manifest file approach was the best way to package dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check line 53 of your POM:

```
<classpathPrefix>lib\</classpathPrefix>
```

Should be:

```
<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
```

Comment: It actually used to be the other way around, but I flipped it to see if it would fix it.